# Is there a way of moving JPanel in BorderLayout?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager

I am using a `BorderLayout` for the frame (the first one that "caught" my attention in the tuts) and a `FlowLayout` for the labels (the one I found appropriate for what I do), and the result shows up like this:

[image]

My objective is to push the "2*1" a little bit down, to sort of "center" it.

I looked around and found a lot of people saying to use a null layout, but then saying it's not the best alternative (even though my window is not resizable), and the other solution I found was using a combo of layouts (unless I misunderstood).

The question is the one on top of this, plus if not, what really is the best alternative? (The following is the code that makes this window (minus the vars and other methods, to simplify visualization).

```
public Frame() {
    super("Jogo de Multiplicar!");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    setSize(300, 200);
    setResizable(false);
    getContentPane().setBackground(pink);

    mensagem = new TransparentPanel();
    operacao = new TransparentPanel();  

    //added stuff in mensagem and operacao

    add(operacao);
    add(mensagem, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}
```

Comment: If I understood what you explained, you can use a GridBagLayout

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height.

Comment: you can use netbeans drag and drop gui creator.

Comment: @scarecrow- The problem with that approach is that unless a programmer knows how to code it by hand, using a GUI designer will produce a poor (& fragile) GUI. Please refrain from giving layout advice until you have more experience at creating cross-platform GUIs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My objective is to push the "2*1" a little bit down, to sort of "center" it.

If you just want more space at the top then you can use a `Border`:

operacao.setBorder( new EmptyBorder(...) );

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Borders](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html) for more information.

If you want to actually center it you can use a `BoxLayout`:

```
Box box = Box.createVerticalBox();
box.add( Box.createVerticalGlue() );
box.add( topPanel );
box.add( Box.createVerticalGlue() );
box.add( bottomPanel );
```

The tutorial also has a section on `How to Use BoxLayout`. Search the table of contents.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `MigLayout` as your only LayoutManager. It's pretty mighty and usually offers everything that the other managers do too.

With this it's pretty simple to center the components:

```
public class MultiplyExample extends JFrame{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    JLabel testLabel = new JLabel("2*2 = 4"); 
    public MultiplyExample(){
        super("Example");
        setBounds(300, 50, 200, 200);
        // Set the MigLayout, so that columns and then rows get centered
        setLayout(new MigLayout("center, center"));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        add(testLabel);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame testFrame = new MultiplyExample();
        testFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Centered Example]

Here is a demo what the `MigLayout` has to offer:

http://www.miglayout.com/swingdemoapp.jnlp

Here is a quickstart-guide:

http://www.miglayout.com/QuickStart.pdf

If you **have** to use `BorderLayout`, you could put your components onto another panel and put this one into the center by using `BorderLayout.CENTER`:

```
pane.add(button, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```